# everything disabled in PiTiVi

Tags: video-editor, pitivi

I'm trying to use PiTiVi... I can import clips from my video camera, but the Render button and all the editing buttons on the bottom toolbar are disabled.  I suspect I need to install some packages but which ones?

I am not stuck on PiTiVi, but since it came with the OS, I was kind of expecting it to be the easiest to use...

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu you running? Have you installed ubuntu-restricted-extras?

Answer (score 4):

If I recall (I reckon it can be found in the Pitivi changelogs since 11.04) I had this AND other problems related to Pitivi. Reason why I went to Openshot and handbreak but anyhow, after some months Pitivi fixed this issue and a lot of memory leaks, crashes and others. So the solution would be to update Pitivi or Ubuntu with Pitivi. On the latest test I did 3 weeks ago, Pitivi is nowhere as it was on 11.04. It is very stable, is not resource hungry and in general I haven't had any crashes.